# Pushing a view from bottom with NavigatorIOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to push a view from the bottom of the screen using react native

Looking at the react native NavigatorIOS documentation I can't find anything.

Any recommendation?

Comment: Actually looking deeper in the documetation it seems that it's possible to do using Navigator instead of  NavigatorIOS

Answer (score -1):

You can do that using Navigator, not NavigatorIOS.
Look at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#configurescene

Here's an example: 
https://github.com/aaronksaunders/React-Modal-Nav-Example

Credits to aaronksaunders